# Meteor: error when displaying data in template

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor and I'm having this error when I try to display a list of items from a mongodb collection.

[image: error]

These are the data that I'm trying to retrieve from my `rewards` collection

[image: rewards collection]

And this is my code:

server/publications.js

```js
Rewards = new Mongo.Collection('rewards');

Meteor.publish('allRewards', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Rewards.find({}, {
            fields: {
                'title': 1,
                'headline': 1,
                'summary': 1,
                'description': 1,
                'requirements': 1
            }
        })
    } else {
        this.ready()
    }
});
```

lib/router.js

```js
Router.route('/rewards', function () {

    var selfRoute = this;

    var rew = RewardsSubs.subscribe("allRewards");
    document.title = "Rewards"

    Tracker.autorun(function (computation) {
        if (RewardsSubs.ready()) {
            selfRoute.render('rewards', {
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        rewards: rew
                    };
                }
            });
            computation.stop()
        } else {
            selfRoute.render('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

client/startup/default.js

```js
RewardsSubs = new SubsManager({
    // maximum number of cache subscriptions
    cacheLimit: 10,
    // any subscription will be expire after 5 minute, if it's not subscribed again
    expireIn: 10
});
```

client/templates/rewards/rewards.html

```html
<template name="rewards">
    <div class="ui container">
        <table class="ui very basic table">
            <tbody>
                {{#each rewards}}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>{{title}}</span>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <h4 class="ui image header">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="header">
                                    . <span>{{headline}}</span>
                                    . <span>{{summary}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </h4>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

I dont know why I'm having this "{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values."...I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is your template code?

Comment: Anyway, i thik your return {
                        rewards: rew
                    }; should be return {
                        rewards: Rewards.find()
                    };

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I forgot that. I just added the template. Concerning to your second comment, I have tried with `ReferenceError: Rewards is not defined` and I'm having a "ReferenceError: Rewards is not defined". 
This Rewards does not refer to the collection that I defined in the publications.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: I finally found the error. The problem was that i was referencing the Rewards collection before the `server/publications.js` was loaded, so the Rewards collection wasn't created yet.

First, I've changed the router.js as @iiro suggested on the comments.

lib/router.js

```js
Router.route('/rewards', function () {

    var selfRoute = this;

    RewardsSubs.subscribe("allRewards");
    document.title = "Rewards"

    Tracker.autorun(function (computation) {
        if (RewardsSubs.ready()) {
            selfRoute.render('rewards', {
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        rewards: Rewards.find()
                    };
                }
            });
            computation.stop()
        } else {
            selfRoute.render('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

Then I've changed the Rewards collection from `server/publications.js` to the `lib` folder

lib/collections/rewards.js

```js
Rewards = new Mongo.Collection('rewards');
```

This problem was related to the [Default file load order in Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order)